# Docker build apt-get update failed to fetch with a 403

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I've seen a few questions about this already but none are the same as my issue. I have a server running Ubuntu 16.04 in our data center so it is technically a virtual machine. I've installed Docker and now I'm trying to build the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
```

The update is failing. I get a bunch of this:

```
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse all Packages
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main all Packages
Ign:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted all Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe all Packages
```

And then:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/source/Sources  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Running `sudo apt-get update` on my server (not in the Docker image) works just fine.

Comment: It happens. It also happens on straight-up servers from time to time.   Re-running, as primitive as it is, may still be the best bet.

Comment: I've ran it a dozen times with identical outcome.

Comment: You could try mapping archive.ubuntu.com to a known-good server (via `/etc/hosts`) to avoid DNS roulette.

Answer (score 1):

I hit something similar: `apt-get update` would fail during `'docker build'` though `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

is set up in the host, and `'sudo apt-get update'` works in the host.

I fixed it as follows:

> **Step 1**:    Copy /etc/apt/apt.conf to the local directory where
>   Dockerfile resides (build context directory for docker).
>
> **Step 2**:  Add the following lines to Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt  
COPY apt.conf /etc/apt`
RUN apt-get update && \ 
  apt-get -y install`
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: @Gregg never reported back... lost in action...